# Implementation issue: Not able to get a list of dicts (Json obj)

Tags: python, json, list, dictionary, sqlalchemy

I am not being able to retrieve the ids and nicknames of friends when the client tries to retrieve a location. id and nickname (along with other content fields) stored in User table and friend relation stored in Friend table. I am new to SQLAlchemy and python in general so any help will be appreciated.

```
obj = encoders.to_json(self, Loc.LOC_JSON_ATTRS)

my_friend_ids = user.Friend.select_friend_ids(requestor_id)

friend_creators = session.query(user.User). \
              join(bc.Bc). \
              filter(and_(
                  user.User.id.in_(my_friend_ids),
                  requestor_id == bc.Bc.creator_id, 
                  self.id == bc.Bc.location_id)). \
              all()


obj['friend_list'] = [{'id': friend.id, 'nickname': friend.nickname} \
                     for friend in friend_creators]
#print obj
if not obj['friend_list']:
    print "empty"

else:
    obj['num_created'] = 0
    obj['num_phollowing'] = 0
    obj['num_collected'] = 0
    obj['friend_list'] = []
```

Comment: What is `self` in this case?  Can you reduce this to a minimal example which demonstrates the problem which we could run?